# Refresh with JPA connection

Tags: java, jpa, orm, ejb-3.0

I'm using EJB3 and I have a problem related to refreshing my `EntityManager`.

The problem is that my apllication must be prepared for use by many people but if one person updates the same date, the `EntityManager` is not bloking that row and it doesn't see the changes other people do after x minutes.

Does anybody know how to refresh an `EntityManager` when I do a 'select', 'insert', 'update' or 'delete'?

Comment: to prevent the last write wins? or before doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a concurrency issue, you should read the [JPA Specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) section 3.4 on Locking and Concurrency. This covers optimistic and pesimistic locking plus the use of versioned attributes.

Aditionally section 3.2.5 covers how to refresh an entity instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh an entity. For e.g.:

```
public void create(MyEntity entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
}

public void edit(MyEntity entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    getEntityManager().flush();
    getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
}
```

Hope this helps.